# Customizing Google Maps by Objective HTML

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps

I am using the [Google Maps plugin by Objective HTML](https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps) for a site I'm working on and am curious to know if it's possible to change the styling of the map it generates?

I have been able to change the styling of a map before using Google's API, but that was just for a static marker on a map. This appears to be slightly different as a plugin so I'm unsure whether a) its possible b) where specific styling code slots in.

There's nothing special about the map, just a standard marker for a channel entry. But it'd be great to know how I can adjust the styles of different elements of the map i.e the water and land colours and how much detailed text is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to customize the map tiles is to follow this example:

https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples/custom-map-styles

Comment: I see you've used the `styles="/assets/js/gmap-styles.js"`. I have made my equivalent of this file but I'm unsure of what actually goes in that file. At the moment I have the following `var stylez = {styles: [{ featureType: "landscape", stylers:.....` Is more than this needed?

Comment: Scratch that, I've taken a look at the file through your site and I have it working through the demo you provided. Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: Can you tell me if MapOptions are customisable too? Such as hiding the zoom function or Map type dropdown

Answer (score 2):

So this site http://snazzymaps.com/ has a bunch of pre-made styles and the JS that goes with them, you might be able to drop their JS into the gmap-styles.js file to get some different custom looks.  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that site. Seem to have it sorted now, just needed to pop those styles into an external file and refer to it in the `styles=` parameter. The styleS on there are really helpful